# Thymeleaf IndexOf array elemt

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

So, I didn't find any useful information online, so I instead ask about it. The problem is relatively simple. I want to get the index of a value in an array in Thymeleaf. I have this code:

```
th:attr="list=${dropdownFields != null && #arrays.contains(dropdownFields[0], y) ?
dropdownFields[1][dropdownFields[0].indexOF(y)] : null}"
```

It's a part of a bigger thing ofc, but I generally only want help with this. As you can see, I currently have: `dropdownFields.indexOF(y)` almost at the end, that's where I get confused, I want to get the same index that is found in the if statement, but now I want to use the index it was found at a different point, to get a different value. Is this somehow possible?
Honestly, all that's important is the question: How do I use `indexOf` in Thymeleaf.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `${#arrays.indexOf(name, frag)}` - for example: `${#arrays.indexOf(dropdownFields[0], y)}`. A full list of these `#` expression utilities is [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects). I am not sure what the underlying structure of the source data is (an array of chars? an array of an array of chars? something else?) - so this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As far as I saw, there doesn't exist a `${#arrays.indexOf(name, frag)}` on the site... So I guess it's not possible? Also, it's an array of numbers, so an integer array

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the comment for `#strings.indexOf` where it says "Also works with arrays, lists or sets". (Java arrays do not have `indexOf`). If so, sorry about that - my mistake.

Comment: Alright.... it somehow works, if I do a normal ´strings.indexOf(a,b)´, it doesn't work and I have to use ´strings.arrayIndexOf(a,b)´ but this poses the problem, that now I get back an array and not an int I can put into the brackets of my array. Now I have to somehow cycle through the indexOf list and set the number in the brackets. But then I would have to copy around 100 lines of code, since if it doesn't find anything, nothing would be shown, and I still want stuff to show just not have that attribute...

Comment: oh, never mind, it doesn't work at all. It can tell me if it does find what I'm searching for, but if I give it an array that is ´{3, 6}´ for example, it shows for both cases the index 0 even if it is searching for 6. It's finding the index 1 but tells me it's 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround for the lack of `indexOf` for your array is to convert the array to a list.

You can do this in Thymeleaf as follows:

```html
<input th:attr="list=${dropdownFields != null && #arrays.contains(dropdownFields, y) 
    ? #lists.toList(dropdownFields).indexOf(y)
    : null}">
```

This assumes your Java array is an object `Integer[]` array not a primitive `int[]` array.

(You can't convert a primitive array to a list - it has to be an object array. Java does not support collections of primitives, in this way.)

So, for example, assuming the Java values as follows:

```java
int y = 23;
Integer[] dropdownFields = new Integer[]{12, 23, 34};
```

Then the above Thymeleaf generates the following HTML:

```html
<input list="1">
```

That `1` means the number `23` is at index 1 in the original array.